# How can I send ajax request NOT include the session cookies in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, session, session-cookies

Looking for a way to skip sessions activity for particular action.

Comment: For that particular action in the controller can't you use :except? Have a look at this http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter and this example. before_filter :authorize, :except => [:index, :show]

Comment: Provide code and scenario